# How to find out the installed (Python) libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, list, visual-studio-code, anaconda, libraries

I have been coding **Python 3.7** using **Visual Studio Code** on Windows 10. Recently, I have taken over a new project, which calls for some newer and different libraries. Hence, for whatever reason, I decided not to customise my libraries, but to install **Anaconda**, and install the corresponding libraries into it.

However, since I cannot remember all the libraries I have already installed in *Visual Studio Code* (e.g. *numPy*, *matplotlib*, etc.), I'd like to ask if there is any way to get a list of the libraries I added on to my Python installation.

I appreciate your comments in advance!

Cheers,

Sina

Comment: I assume you are talking about python libraries, and not about about Visual Studio Code plugins?

Comment: I didn't meantion plugins dude! Just libraries! Yes, Python libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can list your installed libraries using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/quickstart/).

[pip list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/) will give you the list of all installed libraries for its python installation.

*NB: Just make sure you are using the pip.exe from the good install of python, in your case the 3.7 you mentionned*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pip list` command to show all installed packages.

**Windows:**

```
$ py -m pip list [options]
```

**Linux:**

```
$ python -m pip list [options]
```

**Documentation:** https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having VS Code in MacOS M1 and these commands worked for me:

To check the installed ***local*** Python libraries:

For newer versions of Python:

```
pip3 list
```

For older versions of Python:

```
pip list
```

To check the installed ***global*** libraries:

```
brew list
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use conda list to list all the packages installed in anaconda environment

Comment: The question is not about Conda. Please read the question more carefully.